# Scrapy. How to load middleware first?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a question about custom middlewares and **init** function in Scrapy project. Does someone know the way to load middlware firstly, because basicly **init** function is always loading before it?

Answer (score 1):

You want your custom middleware to load first then what exactly?

If it must load before another middleware you can control the order by assigning an smaller integer in the `SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES` setting.

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myproject.middlewares.CustomSpiderMiddleware': 100,
    'myproject.middlewares.CustomSpiderMiddleware2': 50,
}
```

In the example above, `CustomSpiderMiddleware2` will load first, as the middlewares get sorted by their integer value. More info [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#activating-a-spider-middleware).

However, if what you want is to load the middleware before the crawler process is initiated, I don't think that is a trivial way to do it.

Maybe if you can provide more details on what you expect to accomplish, I can be more helpful.

Comment: thank you for your reply. 
I had the same block of code in __init__ method in couple of spiders, so I don't want to duplicate it in every spider, but put it(for example) into some method of custom middleware, so it will be the smarter approach and will not duplicate the __init__ block of code in every spider.